# HP Notebook sign on bios password

Tags: bios, password-recovery

I have an HP notebook model15-bao079dx I have not used it for a while and seem to have tossed the sign on password when cleaning my space (didn't enter it into one of my trusty notebooks). How can I get in? It does not have the original hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it is hard-locked out, pulling the CMOS battery should reset the BIOS